# UICollectionView not calling intrinsicContentSize

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionViewController` which generates cells with a random color for testing purposes. Now that the `UICollectionViewController` is embedded in a `UIScrollView`, I want the scrollView to be the same size as it's `contentSize`.

I made a subclass of `UICollectionView`, implemented `intrinsicContentSize` method, and set the `UICollectionView`'s class to my custom class in IB. However `intrinsicContentSize` never gets called. I have the exact same setup with an `UITableView` and there it works flawlessly.

Any ideas on this?

```c
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize {
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    return CGSizeMake(UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, self.contentSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any constraints set in IB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's happening. Here's another solution to this problem. Set up a height constraint on `UICollectionView` object. Then set its `constant` to be equal to `self.collectionView.contentSize.height`. I use a similar approach in my app, though I've got `UITextView` instead of `UICollectionView`.

**UPDATE:** I've found a way to do this with `intrinsicContentSize`: [UITextView in UIScrollView using auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501720/uitextview-in-uiscrollview-using-auto-layout/19501939#19501939)

Comment: That's the workaround I'm using right now. But anyway I think it would be a 'cleaner' way to use `intrinsicContentSize`. I'll wait if anybody has an idea, otherwise I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @BenLime: I've just made it work in my project. Can you see what happens when you set intrinsic size in IB to `Placeholder`: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5184129/Screenshots/4p0p.png ?

Comment: Still no luck. Tried the `Placeholder` thing in an extra project but I'm experiencing the same behaviour. Anything else you did?

Comment: https://github.com/fastred/UICollectionView-intrinsicContentSize here's how I did it. `intrinsicContentSize:` isn't called on rotation, so it may be a wrong way of doing this in the end.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go with the height constraint mentioned above.

Answer (score 14):

The correct answer is to do something like this

```
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    return self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;
}
```

**And call -invalidateContentSize whenever you think it needs to change (after reloadData for example).**

In Interface Builder you  may need to set placeholder intrinsic size constraints to avoid errors.

This subclassing and overriding of -intrinsicContentSize is useful if you want to grow a collection view's frame until it is constrained by a sibling or parent view

Answer (score -1):

Use this class to make UICollectionView update its intrinsic content size every time the content is changed.

```
class AutosizedCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        registerObserver()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        registerObserver()
    }

    deinit {
        unregisterObserver()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }

    private func registerObserver() {
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UICollectionView.contentSize), options: [], context: nil)
    }

    private func unregisterObserver() {
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(UICollectionView.contentSize))
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
    {
        if keyPath == #keyPath(UICollectionView.contentSize) {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Though, you should understand that if you embed it into another scroll view, cell recycling will not work. The most appreciated way to deal with nested collection view is described [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/05/scrollviews-inside-scrollviews/).