# Objective C - UI List Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to build a fairly detailed home screen for a IOS app and I'm fairly new to IOS dev. it basically contains  -

- Styled button which displays important message count and a link to messages area.
- a iCarousel slider which shows styled stat info
- a tableview with several dynamic custom classes.

All of which are wrapped with a UIScrollView - my issue is I dont know a method of working out the compiled height of the UIScrollview - Is it possible to give it an autoheight?  If not how do I go about generating a height and applying it to the UIView?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to give it an autoheight? If not how do I go about
>   generating a height and applying it to the UIView?

Yes, you can use it with Auto Layout. See the section "Pure Auto Layout Approach" at [UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html). `UITableView` is also a scroll view, so you will have to add a height constraint to it - the height can be calculated with `sizeThatFits:`.

Comment: cheers @Arkadiusz Holko - the UITableView will be the dynamic element - there could be 5 or 15 cells applied depending on certain factors - will this approach allow for that?

Comment: @Dancer: yes, though you'll have to change the constraint's `constant` when the number of elements changes. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360303/uicollectionview-not-calling-intrinsiccontentsize/) may also help you - here we've tried to use `intrinsicContentSize`.